# Configure program using zlib with emscripten

Tags: html, zlib, emscripten

I decided to port some program, that uses zlib, using emscripten. Configuration fails, because it complains no zlib is present on my system.

But:

```
>ls ~/.emscripten_ports/
freetype      libpng      sdl2        sdl2-image.zip  sdl2-ttf.zip  zlib
freetype.zip  libpng.zip  sdl2-image  sdl2-ttf        sdl2.zip      zlib.zip
```

And:

```
> ls ~/.emscripten_cache/asmjs/
dlmalloc.bc  libc.bc       libcxx_noexcept.a  sdl2.bc            sdl2-ttf.bc
freetype.bc  libcxx.a      libpng.bc          sdl2-image.bc      wasm-libc.bc
gl.bc        libcxxabi.bc  ports-builds       sdl2-image-png.bc  zlib.bc
```

And:

```
> ls ~/.emscripten_cache/asmjs/ports-builds/
freetype  include  libpng  sdl2  sdl2-image  sdl2-ttf  zlib
```

I can specify path to zlib with --with-libzlib=dir

How to configure this project? If this information was helpful, I would compile lincity.

I have compiled zlib by myself, using emscripten.

```
emconfigure ./configure --prefix=$PATH_TO_SYSTEM_DIR_IN_EMSCRIPTEN
emmake make
emmake make install
```

I don't know it works, but configure of lincity doesn't complain about missing zlib. It complains about missing libxml-2 and libxml-2 requires python2, so I give up. Put this in an answer?

Comment: You should probably specify the `-s USE_ZLIB=1` compiler option (maybe pass it as `CFLAGS` / `CXXFLAGS` and/or `LDFLAGS`). You can see other options of `emcc` [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js#L698).

Comment: Considering `libxml-2`: it may require "target" python2 (that is, to be built by Emscripten) that may be not trivial, but it may require "host" python2 at build-time (that is, generate something on your build machine before compilation), that should be much simpler and according to Ubuntu package dependencies for built and source packages it looks like the second is right. Another point, `./configure` usually have options such as `--disable-FEATURENAME` that can disable optional features / dependencies.